# Generate search from url

Tags: asp.net

I'm building a webapplication in ASP.NET 4.0.

Now I don't know the terminology for this, so it may be a stupid title and easy to find but I have tried to find a solution before posting here. But I really don't know what this is called..?

**Question:**

 How do I read variables from the URL?

Let's say I type in

www.mysite.com/search/John/Doe

I want to take out "John" and "Doe" directly from the url, and set them as variables.

Also when visiting www.mysite.com, how do I add do so that the info in my textboxes add to the back one the url without reloading the page? But still processes my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in asp.net 4 you can use [Url Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as follows;

In **Globle.asax**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        //define your route pattern here
        RouteTable.Routes.Add("SearchRoute", 
                    new Route("Search/{Firstname}/{Lastname}",
                    new PageRouteHandler("~/SearchPage.aspx")));
}
```

For *www.mysite.com/search/John/Doe*

In **SearchPage.aspx**

```
//access your route values here
string fName = RouteData.Values["Firstname"]; //John
string lName = RouteData.Values["Lastname"];  //Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for URL Mapping/Rewriting, which would parse the URL you're asking about.  Extracting search parameters would be applicable to www.mysite.com/search?FirstName=Joe&LastName=Doe.

ScottGu has an article on URL Mapping/Rewriting here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

It's a bit too complex to answer fully in this forum, but hopefully, Scott's article will give you a start. It lists several options, with examples of each.

Comment: this can be done using [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Nice!   I need to spend more time keeping up with the current tech.

Answer (score 0):

depends, if you are using a normal webform it could be like this:

```
request.Querystring["parameter1"]
```

if you are using MVC then it is defined in you Routing configuration :

```
Controller/Action/Parameters
```

The concept you need to search for in WEBFORMS is ViewState which is the illusion that asp.net has to look like you don't ever loose the form data

Comment: Im webapplication in ASP.NET 4.0. just webform for me :)

Comment: then I think @David gave you just the right reference for it because webforms are file-centric that means usually the address you see points to a certain folder/subfolder/file.aspx  structure. Regarding posting without reloading the page, you need to set javascript